# Call graphql query with react-apollo with asynchronously fetched variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, geolocation, react-apollo

I've got a `react` component which displays a map with points of interest near you.

My HOC uses `react-apollo` to query for those points of interests and give the data as props to the pure UI component.

I'm trying to get the position of the user from `navigator.geolocation` into the variables of my graphql query. But since the navigator API is asynchronous, I can't seem to make it work.

It looks about like this :

```js
const getCurrentPosition = async (settings = {}) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject, settings);
  }
);

const query = gql`
  query($coordinates: [[Float]]){
    whatever(filter: {coordinates: $coordinates}) {
      _id
      coordinates
    }
  }
`;

const withData = graphql(query, {
  options: async (props) => {
    const position = await getCurrentPosition();

    return {
      variables: {
        coordinates: [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude],
      },
    };
  },
  props: ({ data: { loading, whatever, refetch, variables: { coordinates } } }) => ({
    loading,
    whatever,
    coordinates,
    refetch,
  }),
});


const List = ({ loading, whatever, coordinates, refetch }) => {
  if (loading) {
    return null;
  }
  return (/* map display*/);
};

List.propTypes = {
  loading: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  whatever: React.PropTypes.array,
  coordinates: React.PropTypes.array,
  refetch: React.PropTypes.func,
};

export default withData(Map);
```

`coordinates` is always `null` inside my component.

When I log things, it seems that the position is computed but the graphql query and the component rendering happen before it.

The query is not recalled and the component not re-rendered when we get the user location.

Is it possible ? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the asynchronous call beforehand and inject it through props then use http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api.html#graphql-config.skip to skip the query if the position is not here yet.

Maybe using recompose/withProps, etc. ?

Comment: Ended up doing a HOC which retrieves the current location asynchronously and update its state afterwhile. I'll just show a loader until we get the current location, then show the map initialized to the right center.

Comment: Could you show the code so that I can see how it works?